# Shared Server Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dreamhost

I am trying to install an app on a shared server. If i understand properly because i am using a shared server, and that Dreamhost doesn't suppose rails 3.2.8 I must use FCGI, although i am not sure how to install and to make it run properly.

From this tutorial http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Rails_3.

To my understand here what I did,

1. In dreamhost, activate PHP 5.x.x FastCGI and made sure Phusion Passenger is unchecked
2. Create an app on my localmachine
3. Because rails doesn't create a dispatch and access file i create the two following file in my /public folder

dispatch.fcgi
    #!/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
ENV['HOME'] ||= `echo ~`.strip
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby 1.9.3-p327')
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby 1.9.3-p327') + ":" +
    File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby 1.9.3-p327@global')

require 'fcgi' 
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../config/environment')

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
 def initialize(app)
   @app = app
 end

 def call(env)
   env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
   parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
   env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
   env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
   @app.call(env)
 end
end
```

Then created the file
.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L] 

ErrorDocument 500 "Rails application failed to start properly"
```

1. Uploaded to a folder and pointed to the public folder in dreamhost
2. Made sure dispatch.fcgi has 777 for write
3. ssh and run the following command in the public folder : .`/dispatch.fcgi`
4. Crossing my finger but it doesn't work I get the following errors

   ./dispatch.fcgi: line 1: ENV[RAILS_ENV]: command not found
   ./dispatch.fcgi: line 1: =: command not found
   ./dispatch.fcgi: line 2: ENV[HOME]: command not found
   ./dispatch.fcgi: line 2: =: command not found
   ./dispatch.fcgi: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
   ./dispatch.fcgi: line 3:`ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby 1.9.3-p327')'

Doing wrong??? Oh and if i go on the server i get this `Rails application failed to start properly`

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a simlar boat. Make sure you set your username in the first line. Also the last line of the dispatch.fcgi is missing for the rvm verson. Get the last line from the other dispatch example and set your application name.

Last be sure your environment and databases files are set up properly and you have the required gems such as mysql2, fcgi and therubyracer.

I'm not done solving mine yet, but I will make a blog post once I figure out what is needed.